# Getting null values in post wcf service

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, wcf-data-services

I am writing a WCF service. Here is Service side implementation

```
    [OperationContract(Name="GetMediaFile")]
    [Description(ServiceDescConstants.GetMediaFile)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = UriTemplateConstants.GetMediaFile)]        
    Stream GetMediaFile(string type, string mediaId);
```

where

```
UriTemplateConstants.GetMediaFile = "GetMediaFile?type={type}&mediaId={mediaId}";
```

Here is interface method implementation

```
  public Stream GetMediaFile(string type, string mediaId)
    {
            CustomerBL customerBl = new CustomerBL();
            return customerBl.getMediaFile(Convert.ToInt32(type), Convert.ToInt32(mediaId));            
    }
```

On client side I am using RestClient plugin for testing service.
Here is data I am sending

URL : customersite/GetMediaFile
**Header : Content-Type = x-www-form-urlencoded
Body  : type=0&mediaId=1**

Any help !!

Now the PROBLEM is that I am getting null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the interface method:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetMediaFile")]
[Description(ServiceDescConstants.GetMediaFile)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
    UriTemplate = "/GetMediaFile")]
Stream GetMediaFile(Stream input);
```

And also modify it's implementation:

```
public Stream GetMediaFile(Stream input)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Dispose();
    NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);
    string type = qs["type"];
    string mediaId = qs["mediaId"];

    CustomerBL customerBl = new CustomerBL();
    return customerBl.getMediaFile(Convert.ToInt32(type), Convert.ToInt32(mediaId));
}
```

In the *web.config*, use the following configuration (make sure that you use your own namespaces / classes / interfaces names):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfServices.MyService">
      <endpoint address="" 
                name="webEndPoint" 
                behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="WcfServices.IMyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is a sample request:

```
POST /MyService.svc/GetMediaFile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:64531
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

type=0&mediaId=1
```

The solution is an adaptation of Edgardo Rossetto's blog article, [Raw HTTP POST with WCF](http://blogs.southworks.net/erossetto/2007/09/03/raw-http-post-with-wcf/).